# How to properly queue jQuery events with different elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-isotope

I have a grid of photos setup using the jQuery Isotope plugin. When an image is clicked, the person's div is expanded, their bio revealed, and Isotope is called on to update the layout.

It works well the first time, but when clicking on a second image, I'm getting a rubber-banding effect to the animation because it appears to be trying to animate/re-shape in the wrong order. I think it's because I don't have things queued properly?

```
var $people = $('.leadership').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.person',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
        name: '.name',
        category: '[data-category]'
    },
});

$(".person .photo").click(function(){
    $(".person").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    var target = $(this).parent();
    $people.isotope().on( 'layoutComplete', function(){
        console.log(target.offset().top);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top-170
        }, 1000);
    } );

});
```

[dev link in action](http://w3stage.com/ghd/about/leadership/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click handler only should add the `active` class on the right element. That is instantaneous.

Now on `layoutComplete`, which is an event that occurs later... after a layout and all positioning transitions have completed, just use the `active` class to "target" the right element and animate the `scrollTop`.

```
var $people = $('.leadership').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.person',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    category: '[data-category]'
  }
}).on('layoutComplete', function(){
  var target = $(".active");
  console.log(target.offset().top);
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top-170
  }, 1000);
});

$(".person .photo").click(function(){
  $(".person").removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $people.isotope("layout");
});
```

Comment: The problem with this setup is that because the size of the person is changing on click (.active reveals the person's bio), Isotope needs to re-adjust based on the new sizing. (the active person is 100% wide instead of 25% wide)